# Why not use the shield spells to protect against bludgers when playing Quidditch?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

We know that in Harry Potter world there are spells to protect someone from physical object damage (either Protego or other spells, e.g. when Voldemort and Dumbledore dueled in the Ministry.

Why aren't those spelles simply used to help protect players from Bludgers?

Illegal? Too hard?

Canon answers only please.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The official rules of Quidditch are partially described in *[Quidditch Through the Ages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quidditch_Through_the_Ages)*. They are said to have been laid down in 1750 by the Department of Magical Games and Sports. Some of the more common rules are as follows:

> - **Players may take their wands onto the pitch, but they must not be used on or against any players, any player's broomstick, the referee, any of the four balls,** or the spectators. (The right to carry wands at all times was granted during the height of wizard and witch persecution by Muggles, according to Quidditch Through the Ages).
> - Players shall not attack one another by wand, hand or broom.

Comment: That still doesn't tell whether they could cast protective enchantments on themselves before the match.  Also, whether they could wear helmets and mouthguard and other protective clothing against Bludger injuries.

Comment: @b_jonas  If I'm allowed to nitpick. If they cast a spell on themselves they have cast a spell on a player since they are players themselves.

Comment: @Mainstroke: I'm pretty sure that if I cast a prismatic sphere on a bludger it would do a lot of good for me.