# What magical interference is permitted when playing competitive Quidditch?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

It seems that in Quidditch some things are considered as impermissible magical interference, such as drinking Felix Felicis, while other things are fine, such as Hermione magically rainproofing Harry's glasses.

Is there a good rule of thumb of what is and isn't permitted as far as magical interference in competitive Quidditch goes?

I'm specifically interested in 3 things:

- Weather control (getting rid of rain)
- Magically enhancing your abilities, e.g. creating a spell which would serve as a Snitch Radar
- Quidditch Field (enlarge/shrink the hoops?)
- Magical interference *by players* with other players or their equipment? (e.g. push them using a spell, jinx them to be blind using Conjuctivites, etc...) [ **NOTE**: This last bullet was [fully answered by Thaddeus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/22539/976) on a different question ]
- Same as the last one but interference *from spectators*. E.g. could the Slytherin team be legally disqualified if someone from the spectators jinxed a Gryffindor player during a play?

Canon based answers only please.

<sub>DISCLAIMER: the timing of this question was in no way influenced by Lance Armstrong or his doping or lack thereof</sub>

Comment: Just to be clear - I'm not asking if there's a "book of rules" that is mentioned in canon. I'm asking about **contents** of those rules that are mentioned in canon, e.g. QTTA and Pottermore and interviews.

Comment: I'm tempted to VTC this, as the answer to the other question you just asked explicitly explains the rules regarding magical interference.

Comment: @NominSim - weather control is not covered by the other question. Neither is enhancing your own abilities before the match (Snitch Radar).

Comment: I feel like weather control, *and* manipulating the field should fall under using wands *"against any players, any player's broomstick, the referee, any of the four balls, or the spectators."* The spirit of the rule clearly indicates that **if you are affecting the game with a wand, it is against the rules** (it further elaborates that the only reason wands are permitted is that there is a law stating they can be carried at all times).

Comment: @NominSim - strictly speaking, fixing the weather for the better, you are NOT doing anything **against** any players, so it seems technically legal.

Comment: What if I play better than you do in the rain? Then it would be "against" my best interests to let you clear it up. :)

Comment: This is probably at least partly unanswerable.  Quidditch rules are complicated and JKR is unlikely to ever write them down completely.  They might also change every few years like it happens in real sports.

Comment: @b_jonas - JKR promised an encyclopedia of Potterverse at some point.

Comment: What this person said,
"Okay, as far as a good rule of thumb goes, I would imagine that magic used in Quidditch would have to be a spell or charm that does not give the receiver an unfair advantage over any other player, and that every individual playing had access to, such as Cushioning Charms and Braking Charms. For example, say all the members of the Hufflepuff and Gryffindor Quidditch teams wore glasses and couldn't see due to the rain. If they all got the Impervius Charm, fine. No problem. But if only Harry received the charm, that would be inequitable. I looked at all the Quidditch scene

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pottermore doesn't have any groundbreaking info on Quidditch at this time, but rather just a basic overview of what the game is all about.

Personally I deduce from canon that Quidditch is a down and dirty, full-blown contact sport where cheating abounds! Particularly when Gryffindor and Slytherin are playing against each other (well, okay, maybe Slytherin cheats a tad more liberally than Gryffindor. Ambition isn't always pretty.). There aren't many examples of magic used in Quidditch in canon.

In *Prisoner of Azkaban*, Harry, thinking he sees three Dementors, performs the Patronus charm during the Gryffindor/Ravenclaw game; however, it turns out to just be Malfoy, Flint, Crabbe, and Goyle dressed up as Dementors, trying to scare Harry and cause him to faint and fall. Madam Hooch did *not* call a foul on this against Harry. Professor McGonagall took care of business, though:

> ‘An unworthy trick!’ [Professor McGonagall] was shouting. ‘A low and cowardly attempt to sabotage the  Gryffindor Seeker! Detention for all of you, and fifty points from Slytherin! I shall be speaking to Professor Dumbledore about this, make no mistake! Ah, here he comes now!’
>   <sub>*Prisoner of Azkaban* - page 195 - Bloomsbury - chapter 13, *Gryffindor Versus Ravenclaw*</sub>

The above, I believe, technically constitutes spectator interference; however, as Gryffindor was playing Ravenclaw that day, and not Slytherin, it wouldn't make sense to disqualify the Ravenclaw team for a ridiculous stunt Malfoy was responsible for.

That said, I can absolutely see disqualifying the Slytherin team in *Order of the Phoenix* for the *Weasley is our King* antics because Slytherin's Keeper, Bletchley, and the Slytherin spectators were participating in it. But Madam Hooch apparently <strike>was passed out or something</strike> thought otherwise.

You already mentioned the Impervius charm that keeps Harry's glasses clear so he can see (and yet I am mentioned it again ... )

Perhaps it might be possible to cast the Meteolojinx Recanto spell to stop rain:

> ‘Yes, a lot of offices have been raining lately,’ said Mr Weasley. ‘Did you try *meteolojinx recanto*? It worked for Bletchley.’
>   ‘*Meteolojinx recanto*?’ whispered Ron. ‘No, I didn’t. Thanks, D— I mean, thanks, Arthur.’
>   <sub>*Deathly Hallows* - page 210 - Bloomsbury - chapter 13, *The Muggle-Born Registration Commission*</sub>

It's unclear if Meteolojinx Recanto is just for indoor rain, or if it works only in small spaces. I think deliberately changing the weather to benefit a game of Quidditch would be considered weak and unsportsmanlike. Rain, mud, and sports are natural allies :)

In *QTTA* (pages 19-20), a *Daily Profit* article discusses how baskets attached to the hoops were disallowed, as it was impossible to standardize the size of the baskets. Why magical witches and wizards couldn't standardize baskets, I don't know.

Perhaps purposeful *failure* to knock nearby Bludgers away would constitute a foul if the Beaters' deliberate negligence caused one of their teammates to be injured. (*QTTA* pages 22-23)

Okay, as far as a good rule of thumb goes, **I would imagine that magic used in Quidditch would have to be a spell or charm that does *not* give the receiver an unfair advantage over any other player, and that every individual playing had access to, such as Cushioning Charms and Braking Charms.** For example, say all the members of the Hufflepuff and Gryffindor Quidditch teams wore glasses and couldn't see due to the rain. If they all got the Impervius Charm, fine. No problem. But if only Harry received the charm, that would be inequitable.

I looked at all the Quidditch scenes in the books and I actually didn't find an example, other than the Patronus Charm, of magic being used *by one of the players* in the game.

<sub>If the exhibition of Muggle duelling counts, then Harry, George, and Fred received a lifetime ban from Quidditch by Umbridge after they beat up Draco Malfoy following the Gryffindor/Slytherin game in *Order of the Phoenix*.</sub>

Comment: I don't think Umbridge was working based on any rules :)

Comment: “a down and dirty, full-blown contact sport where cheating abounds”. Do you mean “a sport”? :P

Comment: "Meteolojinx Recanto" sounds like a spell to recant (which means to withdraw or relinquish) a "Meteolojinx". It sounds like a counter spell to something else which causes rain, not an all-purpose "Stop the rain" spell. Think "Lumos" and "Nox" - "Nox" doesn't extinguish light, just the one created by "Lumos".

Comment: "Meteolojinx Recanto" is cod-Latin for "undo the weather spell".